# Can we measure the spin in a direction perpendicular to the magnetic field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I have read from several sources that in presence of an external magnetic field the electron spin aligns to it either parallel or antiparallel.

On the other hand, I have also read that when the magnetic field is in the Z direction, the mean value for the $<S_x>$ will vary in the time as $sin(\alpha)*sin(\Omega t)$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between the spin and the external field and  $sin(\Omega t)$ is the precession term.

The first statement seems to agree with real experiments such as the Stern Gerlach experiment, but I wonder if the second result is just a theoretical consequence of Quantum Mechanics or if it is possible to measure the spin in a direction different from the external field provided that the field aligns with it.

Comment: read from what sources?

Comment: A Texas university lesson about the spin precession: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node91.html